# Implement data structure and query for params

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to create this data stricture:

```
Map<String, Country> table = new HashMap<>();
table.put("AF", new Country("Afghanistan", "AFG", "004"));
// 300 more  

class Country {

        private String country;
        private String alpha3;
        private String number;

        public Country(String country, String alpha3, String number) {

            this.country = country;
            this.alpha3 = alpha3;
            this.number = number;
        } 
}
```

Second way:

```
Map<String, Country> table = new HashMap<>();
Table<String, String, Integer> table2 = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put("AF", HashBasedTable.create().put("Afghanistan", "AFG", "004"));
// 300 more
```

I want to search values into the data structure values based on keys that I send:

- numeric code from country name
- country code from country name
- alpha3 code from country name

What is the bast way to implement this search into the second data structure?

Comment: `new Country` this will not compile, you would need to declare your map as : `Map<String, Country*>` (smart pointer would be better). What is `HashBasedTable`?

Comment: This is from Guava library `com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable`

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was c++

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` contains a method called `forEach(BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action)` which can be used to iterate through each key-value pair in your `HashMap`.

Therefore, using a lambda you can do something like this:

```
//Search a HashMap of employee ID/name records by name, for their ID number.
public int getID(HashMap<Integer, String> employees, String name) {
    //Iterate through every key-value pair, performing the lambda's operation on it.
    employees.forEach((Integer j, String k) -> {
        if(k.equals(name)) return Integer.valueOf(j); //If the value matches the name, return the ID
    }
    return -1;
}
```